# Property of a basis

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V:=\Bbb R^3$ and $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be its standard basis.
Let $v_1=e_1+3e_2+4e_3$ and $v_2=7e_2+2e_3$
Without using the concept of dimension, show that $(v_1,v_2)$ is not a basis of $V$. Find a vector which is not in $\text{span}(v_1,v_2)$.

Comment: $v_3=e_1$ is valid.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks but do you know the general solution? Just in case $v_1$ and $v_2$ were different.

Comment: I see the following way: Determinant of some matrix is not equal to zero.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg can I say $v_1 - v_2 = e_1 -4e_2 +2e_3$ then I cancel out some term of the equation, let's say $e_1$ so that $v_3 = -4e_2+2e_3$ is a vector that does not belong to the span $(v_1,v_2)$?
Can I consider this a general way of finding out the vector?

Comment: Any general solution would, under the hood, be essentially proving that $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be spanned by two vectors (which is an argument it seems you can't make here). If $v_1 = ae_1 + be_2 + ce_2$ and $v_2 = xe_1 + ye_2 + ze_2$, your question is asking if $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ x & y & z\end{bmatrix}$ has trivial null space.

Comment: @Mazen Draw  You can calculate $v_1\times v_2$, but for $v_1||v_2$ it does not work.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg so you chose to find the vector that is perpendicular to the plane that contains $(v_1,v_2)$. I like this way.

Comment: @Mazen Draw If so I'll post it.

Comment: In the case when you would just need one vector, you can just choose a random vector in $\mathbb R^3$. It will almost surely not be in the span. And if you have extremely bad luck, you can just temper with your guess a bit to fly out of the span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate $v_1\times v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to directly use definition of span: $v\in\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$ iff $v = \alpha v_1+\beta v_2$, for some scalars $\alpha,$ $\beta$. That means that $\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\} = \{(\alpha,3\alpha+7\beta,4\alpha+2\beta) \mid \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R\}.$ You can use this parametrization to find vectors not in span. Notice that giving first two coordinates of vector in the span completely determines $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which in turn completely determines the third coordinate. So, if $(1,10,?)$ is in the span, $\alpha = \beta = 1$, so the third coordinate is $6$. That means that $(1,10,z)$ is not in the span for any $z\neq 6$.

Another way to do it is to notice that $(x,y,z)$ is in the span if and only if $$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y & z \\
1 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 7 & 2 
\end{pmatrix} = 0.$$

This is because if that determinant weren't $0$, the matrix would be invertible, which is equivalent to being of full rank, meaning that rows are linearly independent. Conversely, by determinant being $0$ we have that the matrix is not of full rank and consequently that $(x,y,z)$ is in the span.

If you calculate the determinant, you get that $(x,y,z)$ is in the span if and only if $$24x+2y-7z = 0.$$
All you have to do now is find a triplet that is not a solution.